# alignment the text and the horizontal rule with same width

Tags: javascript, html, css

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>project-1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="company-name">
                <p class="title">OneClick</p>
                <div class="title horizontal-line"></span>
                <p id="p-clear" class="title ">Tech Solution</p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.title{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}
.horizontal-line{
        border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.company-name{
    width:20%;
}
```

in this code i need output like below please help me to solve the issue
[I need like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlGIt.png)
[but the output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6USg.png)
help me to solve the issue

Comment: Change style from ```.company-name{width:20%;}``` to ```#company-name{width:20%;}```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*small mistake in your code you used `id` instead of `class`

I just modified the below code

```
<div class="company-name"> to <div id="company-name">
```

```css
.title{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}
.horizontal-line{
        border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.company-name{
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>project-1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="company-name">
                <p class="title">OneClick</p>
                <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
                <p id="p-clear" class="title ">Tech Solution</p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```